# invalid use of non-static data member 'Board::N'

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

This is the header:

```
class Board {
public:
    friend class Game;

    Board() = default;
    Board(int n) : N(n) { }

    Board& SetType(int, int, char);
    void GetType(int, int);
    Board& CreateEmptyBoard();
    void BoardDisplay();

private:
    int N = 0;// dimension
    char Maze[15][15];

    const static int MaxSize = 15;
};

class Game {
public:
    Game() = default;
    Game(int x, int y) : PosX(x), PosY(y) { }

    void BuildGame();
    void GameDisplay();
    void MoveUp();
    void MoveDown();
    void MoveLeft();
    void MoveRight();

private:
    int PosX = 0;
    int PosY = 0;
};

void Game::BuildGame() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < Board::N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Board::N; j++) {
            if (i == rand() % (Board::N) && j == rand() % (Board::N))
                Board::Board& SetType(i, j, 'W');
        }
    }
}
```

In class Game's member function `void BuildGame`,I want to call member function`Board& SetType(int,int,char)` in class Board.I define this function in a header file and not show here. Then I build the project, I got `invalid use of non-static data member 'Board::N'` and `'SetType' was not declared in this scope`. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYrey.png)

Where I wrong? I can't find it.

Comment: @ildjarn I seriously doubt this would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is letting you know that you are using an instance variable as a static. A static variable is associated with an entire class and not a single object, so it is called through the class name and not an object of the class. but it would need to be marked as static like so

```
class Board
{
    public:
        static Board& setType(int, int, char);
        ...
    private:
        static int N;
        ...
}
```

my instinct however tells me that you want to use it at an instance level, so you would write your `void Game::buildGame()` method using a `Board` that it creates (possibly making it an attribute of the `Game` class:

```
void Game::BuildGame() {
    //make your board here. alternatively make an instance of the game
    Board myBoard();
    srand(time(NULL));
    //in the following, use myBoard as the instance of a board.
    for (int i = 0; i < myBoard.N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myBoard.N; j++) {
            if (i == rand() % (myBoard.N) && j == rand() % (Board::N))
                myBoard.setType(i, j, 'W');
        }
    }
}
```

And a `Board` class that looks something like this. You will probably want your `setType` method to modify the instance and return void instead of returning another board reference.

```
class Board
{
    public:
        //this one will change this particular Board instance.
        void setType(int, int, char);
        //this one may make sense to be static if it is a factory method
        //but why not use a constructor instead?
        static Board& createEmptyBoard();
        //maybe you meant something to reset the board to empty state.
        void resetBoardToEmpty();
        ...
    private:
        int N;
        ...
}
```

while you're at it you might make it a `struct` (which has members public by default) as it seems to be a "hidden" holder class for the game, and this would alleviate the need to use a `friend class` (these are to be used judiciously as they can get messy really fast). using a `struct` would also allow you to make a `ChessGame` class that reuses the `Board` struct.

Answer (score 0):

`N` isn't a static member of class `Board`, hence you'll need an instance of board to access it.

---

Your `Game` class actually needs to have a `Board` member variable to achieve that above mentioned instance.